# BufferedReader reading paragraph from .txt file and drawing as String

Tags: java, arraylist, split, bufferedreader

So, I have looked at about 11 questions similar to what I am looking for, but the solutions have not helped me unfortunately. I have a text file containing instructions for a game I am making. This is one paragraph and **I want to go to the next line by using `\n` in the file**. From what I have learned, this can be done by utilizing `.split()`. I have tried learning about and using this, but as I said, I have not come far. **So basically I want to read my file using `BufferedReader` and then every time `\n` is read, go to the next line and put all of these Strings in an ArrayList**. However, is it then possible to **`drawString()`** by calling the ArrayList and using a `for-loop` to change the `y value` in order to print the lines under the last one?

Comment: Plesse focus on one thing per question and ask multiple questions if you have more than one thing. Reading text and drawing it are two completely separate issues.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sorry, maybe my question isn't clear. I have one problem and it is that I cannot figure out how to draw the paragraph read from the text file, as a **paragraph** and not as one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read use:

```
File file = new File("foo.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file));
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
 doSomething(line);
}

//EDIT: if you want to get all your lines to one String that seperates the lines with \n replace doSomething(line) with
String str = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
 str+=line.concat("\n");
}
```

To write:

```
    File file = new File("foo.txt");
    String[] data = getMyData();// replace the method call with whatever you need
    final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    for (final String s : data) {
                writer.write(s);
                writer.newLine();
    }
```

these two code snippets will work together.

EDIT2:
If you have the following String

```
String str = "firstXsecondXthird";
```

then

```
String strings[] = str.split("X");
```

will give you an array with 3 strings:

```
strings[0] first
strings[1] second
strings[2] third
```

Comment: So I have your first portion, but it does not save line-by-line. I currently save it to a String called line. So I am given my whole paragraph as a one line string. Now based on the searches I've been doing, apparently there is a way to use `split` to save to one thing but go to the next line?

Comment: ahh ok, so you have ONE big line, with each 'paragraph' seperated by some character lets call it 'x' - then can you explain why String.split(x); is not working for your purpose?
EDIT: Split will give you an array of ALL the different strings that are seperated by the regex you give it.

Comment: Ok so i have one paragraph in the text file. I then use the same thing that is your first portion to read this in. But then when I go to draw it, it draws as one long line. Other SO posts suggest using a for loop like `for (String line: text.split("\n"))`. So I tried this and nothing changed, maybe I used it wrong...

Comment: Try "\\n", if your text file contains \n, that could do the trick.
String.split("\\n") instead of String.split("\n");

Comment: `//EDIT: if you want to get all your lines to one String that seperates the lines with \n replace doSomething(line) with
String str = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
 str+=line.concat("\n");` **Could you explain this?, I tried it and nothing changed :/**

Comment: This was to put in multiple strings into one line seperated by "\n".
Since you already have that, you dont need this part. I think your problem is that you have your paragraph in ONE line, with different parts seperated by "\n". "\n" is taken as line seperator, so if you want to split by that you need to use 2 backslashes instead of one, to tell it that you actually want to split by the characters backslash n instead of the newline operator.

Comment: FINALLY got it working! I played around with your array solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A `BufferedReader` can already split the input on newlines:

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("foo.txt"));
String line;

while((line = b.readLine()) != null){
   //do stuff, line is current line
}
```

Comment: I've done this, but I get one long string instead of the paragraph written in my text file. I want to use this but also make sure its not drawn as one line, but multiple.

Comment: If you want to read something line-by-line, you also need to save your text line-by-line. check my anwser if that is what your need, if not, please clarify how your data is saved.